# PHP MySql time calculations

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, timestamp

I want to calculate how much time the worker has left since break start.

By the click, PHP insert into history table a record with timestamp (break_start), after second click, PHP update record with timestamp (break_end). 
Now i can calculate time difference using this code:

```
$break_start = $worker->query('SELECT break_start FROM history WHERE id = 16')->fetchArray();

$break_end = $worker->query('SELECT break_end FROM history WHERE id = 16')->fetchArray();
$diff = $worker->query("SELECT TIMEDIFF('".$break_end['break_end']."','".$break_start['break_start']."') AS total")->fetchArray();


$break_total = $worker->query("SELECT break_time FROM worker WHERE id = 7")->fetchArray();

echo $diff['total']." ";

echo $break_total['break_time']." ";

$str1 = strtotime($diff['total']);
$str2 = strtotime($break_total['break_time']);
```

Output is: `00:31:26 00:30:00.00 86 01:26`

(This code above is just attempt to understand time in PHP and MySQL).

I want to subtract break time from "break" value which is stored in table "worker" (default value is 30).

I don`t know how to do this..

Comment: You can substract using `-`. So in theory, `echo $diff = $str1 - $str2;` I tend to think would work.

Comment: I  missed an important thing. I want to substract time in every case of worker break. So for example - First brake 10 minutes:    **Get "brake_time" record (30 in defualt) minus 10 minutes and update result (20 minutes) into break_time record in worker table.
 Second brake 5 minutes: Get "brake_time" record (30 in defualt) minus 10 minutes and update result (15 minutes) into break_time record in worker** 
Which type of time i have to update if row "break_time" has "time" type?

Comment: I would recommend not using `TIME` columns if you're storing durations. Use an `INT` column of appropriate size and store the number of minutes instead. Your question is unclear about what results you're looking for.